# PHP Datepicker Validate if age is lower than 18 years old

Tags: javascript, php, validation

Can I do a warning validate from Datepicker and alert swal like this?

I do that and it error that `is_string` is not defined.

I'm new in php btw

The comment is a think that i tried to make in different way sorry abort that.

form

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Birthdate</label>
    <div class="input-group date">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control datepicker_class" id="birth_date" name="birth_date" onchange="validateAge">
    </div>
</div>
```

function

```
function validateAge(){
var birthday = new $('#birth_date').val();
// let birthday = $('#birth_date').val();

// check = explode('/',birthday);
birthday = explode("/", birthday);
// alert(check);

if (is_string(birthday)) {
    birthday = strtotime(birthday);
}

// check
// 31536000 is the number of seconds in a 365 days year. strtotime for 1 years : 31556926 
if(time() - birthday < 18 * 31556926)  {
    swal({
            title: "warning",
            text: "your age is lower than 18",
            type: "warning"
        });
}

return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi Dashi and welcome to SO. It looks like you're trying to write PHP inside a JavaScript function. Unfortunately you can't combine the two like this. PHP can only be interpreted on the server, and JavaScript is what runs in the browser when we visit a site. So in your case you can only use JavaScript code to write your validation. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: oh ok , that's why it error like that 
I didn't know that before , I'm just a newbie in php sorry abort that hahaha

Comment: That's okay. Feel free to delete your question if it is no longer relevant.

Comment: I'm gonna try to make it correct , but I don't know how to make it correctly 
but I will try in another way.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript there is no is_string() function. To check if variable is string you can do it this way:

```
if (typeof birthday === 'string' || birthday instanceof String) 
//string
else
//not string
```

Comment: i'will try this thx

Comment: And if you know what some function does in PHP you can always google for alternatives in another language for example PHP is_string in javascript, and it will most likely lead you to js version of PHP function